# Subtract fiscal year quarters from current date using Java LocalDate

Tags: java, date, divide

By using Java `LocalDate` how can I subtract eight quarters from the current quarter?

For example:

> 2019 Q3 - (8 x quarter) = 2017 Q4

I've tried using

```
LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
now.minus(1, IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR);
```

but I am getting a negative value and I don't know how to handle this.

Comment: Instead of trying to describe your code, please [edit] your question to include the code in question, including any errors, input, expected vs actual output, etc.  A [mcve] would be ideal.

Comment: How do you get "2019 Q3 - (8 x quarter) = 2017 Q4"? 8 quarters = 2 years, so surely that should be 2017 Q3?

Comment: Works well enough for me if I use the relevant constant (unit, not field) : https://ideone.com/shivtr. I had a compilation exception when I didn't though.

Comment: Are you working with calendar quarters or financial year quarters?

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear" without any definition of "quarters".

Comment: @BasilBourque aren't financial year quarters exactly the same length as calendar year quarters, just that they start at a different time of year? If so, then the subtraction would still give the same result irrespective of which type of quarter we are talking about.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `QUARTER_OF_YEAR` which is of type `TimeField`. You should use [`IsoFields.QUARTER_YEARS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html#QUARTER_YEARS) which is of type `TemporalUnit`:

> Unit that represents the concept of a quarter-year. For the ISO calendar system, it is equal to 3 months.

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
LocalDate ago = now.minus(3, IsoFields.QUARTER_YEARS);
System.out.println(ago);
```

Comment: This code uses the ISO 8601 standard definition of quarters. But the title of the Question says "fiscal year quarters" which likely follows a different definition of "quarter". So I am not sure this Answer addresses the Question.